# Nusoap change returnname

Tags: php, nusoap

I'd like to change the tag that is currently 'return' to 'result'. Like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" 
 xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
 xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
 xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
  <ns1:AuthenticateResponse xmlns:ns1="http://tempuri.org">
     <***return***>
     <Result xsi:type="xsd:string">OK</Result>
     </***return***>
  </ns1:AuthenticateResponse>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

(see the value between the `***`)

Is this possible? And if so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed this myself by changing the nusoap.php file (`line 4143` like this:

original:

```
$return_val = $this->serialize_val($this->methodreturn, 'return');
```

Edited code:

```
$return_val = $this->serialize_val($this->methodreturn, 'result');
```

I bet there is a better way of handling this, but this fixes it for me.